# see if value exists in multiple arrays, change value in one array if it does

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Say that I had the following two arrays:

```js
var arrToChangeAndCompare = [{name:'Bob'},{name:'Joe'},{name:'Alise'},{name:'Joe1'}];
var arrToCompare = [{name:'Frank'},{name:'Joe'},{name:'Jen'},{name:'Joe1'}];
```

And I want to first array to only contain unique names in the array its in, but also unique names compared to the second array (arrToCompare). To be clear, I don't want to REMOVE values that are not unique, I want to CHANGE them in "arrToChangeAndCompare" so they are then unique to both arrays. Keep in mind that if there are non-unique values in "arrToCompare", this does not matter. The only rule is that the "arrToChangeAndCompare" only has unique names in its array and names that are unique compared to "arrToCompare" as well.

I have the following code that almost does what I want, but it doesn't check the second array again once it changes a value in the first array to be unique, which results in the "arr" array to have all unique values, but the "arr" values are not unique in both arrays (Joe1 exists in the first array and the second array).

**ALMOST WORKING CODE**

```js
var arr = [{name:'Bob'},{name:'Joe'},{name:'Alise'},{name:'Joe1'}];
var arr2 = [{name:'Frank'},{name:'Joe'},{name:'Jen'},{name:'Joe1'}];

var arr3;
arr2.forEach(e2 => {
    arr3 = arr.map(e => {
        var name = e.name.match(/[a-zA-Z]*/)[0]
        if (e2.name === name) {
            var number = e.name.match(/[0-9]+/)
            if (number) {
                e.name = name + (+number[0] + 1)
            } else {
                e.name = name + 1
            }
        }
        return e 
    })
})
console.log(arr3)
```

The expected output of arrays listed at the top would be one array that looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Bob"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Alise"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe3"
  }
]
```

**EXPLANATION OF OUTPUT**

1. Bob is unique, so no actual is done for the first object in `arrToChangeAndCompare`
2. Joe is not unique compared to the `arrtoCompare`, so its number needs to be changed. But, since Joe1 exists in `arrToChangeAndCompare` as well, it has to be incremented again to Joe2
3. Alise is unique to both arrays, so no actual is done for the third object in `arrToChangeAndCompare`
4. Joe1 is not unique compared to `arrtoCompare`, so Joe1 must be incremented to Joe2, But since Joe2 also exists in `arrToChangeAndCompare`, it must then be incremented to Joe3
5. All values in `arrToChangeAndCompare` are now unique compared to its own array and `arrtoCompare`

Please ask additional questions as needed. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with `name` and the letter parts of `name` and check against.

If not found add string to set and return the value.

If found take letters, digits and increment the numerical value until no more combined string is in the set. Then update the set and return the new string.

```js
var array1 = [{ name: 'Bob', foo: 42 }, { name: 'Bob', bar: 42 }, { name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Alise' }, { name: 'Joe1' }],
    array2 = [{ name: 'Frank' }, { name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Jen' }, { name: 'Joe1' }],
    items = array2.reduce((s, { name }) => s.add(name).add(name.match(/^\D+/)[0]), new Set),
    result = array1.map(({ name, ...o }) => {
        if (!items.has(name)) {
            items.add(name);
            return { name, ...o };
        }
        var [letters, digits = 0] = name.split(/(\d+)/);
        digits = +digits;
        while (items.has(letters + ++digits));
        items.add(letters + digits);
        return { name: letters + digits, ...o };
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is wonderful @Nina Scholz. How would this work on an array of objects like I have in my post?

Comment: this wouldn't work if array has `Joe3`. Your logic will result in multiple Joe3

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz. It doesn't look like it works if there are multiple values in the first array that do not appear in the second array. For Example, if you try these two arrays: var array1 = [{ name: 'Bob' },{ name: 'Bob' },{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Joe' },{ name: 'Joe' },{ name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Alise' }, { name: 'Joe1' }],
    array2 = [{ name: 'Frank' }, { name: 'Joe' }, { name: 'Jen' }, { name: 'Joe1' }],

Comment: what is the wanted result?

Comment: [
  {
    "name": "Bob"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe3"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Alise"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe5"
  }
]

Comment: Also, @NinaScholz, how would I map multiple properties with the code you provided? For example, I am mapping them by name, but they have other properties that need to also be mapped to the result. Sorry for the multiple questions! I REALLY appreciate your help.

Comment: it take the unused properties out of the object and add all unused properties to the new objects.